# Where did the idea of the 'City in Bottle' originate?

Tags: history-of

Where did the well known trope of a 'City in a Bottle', as associated with middle eastern mythology, originate?

It is referenced in modern culture (see the City in a Bottle *Magic: the Gathering* Card, [*Sandman* #50: Ramadan](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sandman_Vol_2_50) by Neil Gaiman, etc), and is always associated with the Middle East, Arabia in particular. I thought that it originated somewhere in the *1001 Nights*, but I have not been able to locate the particular story.

Can anyone shed light on the origins of this concept?

Comment: Again, I'm not convinced it has anything to do with Middle Eastern mythology. If you have some specific reference it woudl help your question to add it.

Comment: There is apparently a "Bottle City Of Kandor" from the Superman comic books, and there is "[The Crystal Crypt](https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/the-crystal-crypt/)" by Phillip K. Dick about a weapon of sorts that is used to miniaturize a city so it can be smuggled out on a transport.

Comment: Perhaps the Arabic connection comes from Aladdin's genie?  Although that was a lamp, not a bottle.

Comment: Cross-post at https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/5483/197

Comment: @b_jonas That was a result of me telling OP it belonged here rather than there.

Comment: The obvious point of reference is RA Heinlein's "[Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7992983-universe)". I wonder if our expert searchers can find anything earlier.

Comment: Hmmm... I found this article, stating that the Magic the Gathering card was actually based upon the Sandman story: https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-arabian-nights-2002-08-05

Comment: It seems that the sandman story might be the origin of the idea as related to the middle east.